# (iOS 4.x) Cleaning out the NSUserDefaults when app quits

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

So I have been doing a lot of reading about the way iOS handles application state notifications, and it looks like they may have created a problem for me in iOS 4.

Before 4.x, I was cleaning out my NSUserDefaults in the `- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {}` delegate method.

Unfortunately, it does not look like this method is used anymore when the user quits the app from the desktop (pressing the red "-").  Instead the app receives a SIGKIL.  Has anyone schemed a way to capture this and do something when the app is terminated (such as clean out the UserDefaults)?  I would prefer to not disable the multitasking since that's non-standard behavior.  Any help at all would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That method will still be sent if iOS ever decides to quit the app. You should probably put the same cleanup code in [applicationWillResignActive:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) if you want it to clean up when moving to the background as well.

However, if you say you want to support multitasking, why are you wiping the default? Shouldn't the user be able to come back to the app exactly as they left it?

Comment: That's exactly my point.  I only want to wipe it when the app fully quits.  It should be able to run in the background still, and resume when needed...

Comment: I ended up rethinking my data structures to accommodate this problem and went with this route.  Thanks for the help.  :D

Answer (score 0):

By "clean out" do you mean "synchronize to disk"? (i.e. by calling -synchronize)

If so, NSUserDefaults handles this for you automatically, no need to worry about it.

Comment: synchronise is run periodically, however there is no guarantee that it will be called before your app is killed.

Comment: Unless your application is killed unexpectedly (i.e. in response to memory pressure, or due to a crash), it will have its preferences synchronized during termination. If this isn't a documented guarantee, it should be (possibly worth filing a bug on if so). Also, "periodically" is not quite the right phrasing. It's a coalescing interval after any pref is set.

Comment: No I don't want it synchonized.  I want to remove some stuff I don't want saved from it before the app closes.  I used to be able to do that before 4.x in the `applicationWillTerminate` method.  But that does not get called anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You still need the code in applicationWillTerminate: for those iOS 4 devices that don't support multi-tasking. But you'll also need to call the same code when the app goes into the background (applicationDidEnterBackground:). You might also consider applicationWillResignActive:, but this would get called when a call or an SMS arrives rather than only when it goes into the background.

Comment: See my response to bobDevil's answer.  I don't want to do anything with it when it enters the background...

Comment: In that case your only option is to disable the multitasking (`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`) as there is no way to intercept the "kill" when your app is in the background.

Comment: Ah man, that's a ball buster.  There is no way to set up a notification to listen for the SIGKIL message?

Comment: After doing some more reading, it looks like there isn't.  It would be the equivalent of malware.  :x  I think that I can do what I need based on the applicationWillResignActive method.  Thanks for the guidance Stephen.